# Create multi column view from single column data

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have the following result from my SQL query:

```
EventID          P_Num  PN_NameCount1   PN_Name
ABC-I-10942683  1089213     1            Company 1
ABC-I-10942683  1326624     8            Company 2
```

I am still learning this capability in SQL and need some assistance, Pivot's are NOT working in this scenario.

I have tried several different ways in attempting to do this, but was not able to create the desired results:

```
EventID          P_Num1     PNC1    PN_Name     PNC_Num2      PNC2  PN_Name
ABC-I-10942683  1089213     1       Company     11326624        8   Company 2
```

The `EventID` will change based on the different events from the companies, as the `EventID` is based on a particular date the event occurred with the company.

This is just a sample of the 500K+ rows of data I am working with. This will go into a temp table to be joined with the other various pieces of data needed.

I have tried this without success:

```
  SELECT Key, 
         MAX(Col1) AS Col1, 
         MAX(Col2) AS Col2, 
         MAX(Col3) AS Col3 
    FROM table 
GROUP BY Key
```

Comment: What if you have 3 or 4 or X for the same EventID?

Comment: The only way I can think you can solve this directly in MySQL is creating a script that builds the SQL string dinamically, and then use that SQL string with a prepared statement. I think this can help you: http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html

Comment: @BLAM...for 3 or 4 I will need to show also, but I just need help with getting there. I can always add more columns once I am able to get 1 and 2 separated.

Comment: @Prix...I tried this structure but did not have any positive results. 
      select 
         Key,
         max(Col1) as Col1,
         max(Col2) as Col2,
         max(Col3) as Col3
      from table
      group by Key

Comment: @Barrabka...the link given is not working. ALso PIVOTS although they are nice, they will not work when I write them out. (Not a recognized function).

Comment: @BLAM...the answer you provided worked...I am unable to check it as it has disappeared from the post.

Comment: MIN and MAX are working correctly from the post that BLAM replied on however, would would I include all of the in between data from Min to MAX? When I tried to add more cloumns it would repeat the current results. Maybe I am over thinking the simple, here. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select EventID 
, min(P_Num) as P_Num1, min(PN_NameCount1)  PNC1, min(PN_Name) as PN_Name1
, max(P_Num) as P_Num2, max(PN_NameCount1)  PNC2, max(PN_Name) as PN_Name2 
from table 
group by EventID
```

This is an answer to the stated question.  And you stated in a comment you could extend it.